# How to use reserved keywords as column names in orientdb?

Tags: java, orientdb

I want to use "id" as a property name for a vertex in orientdb. I am using the tinkerpop api.

I can use "id" as a property name if I am directly inserting data via JSON.

```
INSERT INTO PERSON CONTENT{"id":1}
```

But  I am not able to do that from JAVA.

```
vertex.setProperty("id", 1, OType.INTEGER);
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property key is reserved for all elements: id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
OrientGraph graph=new OrientGraph(currentPath); 

OClass person = graph.getRawGraph().getMetadata().getSchema().getClass("Person");
person.createProperty("id", OType.STRING);
```

Comment: person.createProperty("id", OType.STRING);

Comment: I already have created the property "id" from the orient studio. I am getting error when I am setting this property to Vertex.  

vertex.setProperty("id", 1,  OType.INTEGER);

Comment: Try this vertex.setProperties("id",1);

Comment: the property id must be declared of type Integer

Comment: You can edit your own posts at any time and fix errors.

Comment: @AlessandroRota I have declared the property "id" as Integer type only.  In mysql we have the facility to surround the keyword with the character backtick ("`") for using reserved keywords. Is there any similar things for orientdb?

Answer (score 0):

The reason of such exception is because this is against Blueprints standard.
However, you can always disable such constraints with:  `graph.setStandardElementConstraints(false)`.